# Find an amplifier voltage output to match my subwoofer rating

Tags: measurement, output, sound, watts

I have two amplifiers with a subwoofer connected to each one and I was wondering how to check what the output wattage to make sure I don't blow my subs.  Since they are two exact same pairs, I'll just use one for the example and do the same for both when I get an answer.

My amplifier is a [SSL EVO4000.1](https://soundstormlab.com/product/evo4000-1/) which can output 750W RMS @ 4 Ohm

My sub is a [Psi](https://psicaraudio.com/product/12-bass-line/)  with 750W RMS DVC(Dual Voice Coil) and 2 ohm option. The voice coils are connected in series for 750W RMS @ 4 Ohm

Thing is, I have no idea how to make sure I don't blow either of them. So I was hoping there's a way to check the output of the amplifier with my meter and convert it to know the wattage output.

EDIT: If anyone can help but need more details about anything (that is not in the products page) just tell me in comments, I'll do my best to find the infos.

Comment: Submarine? Substrate? Sub sandwich? Substitute teacher? It is best to avoid slang here; we deal with a very broad range of topics.

Comment: You have written something which can be guessed to have meaning "your amp can output continuously 750W RMS to a 4 Ohm load and your speaker is a 4 Ohm load which can stand continuous 750 W RMS input". I say guess because without having plausible engineering quality datasheets only guesses are possible. Nobody here can do more than guess. Know that proper datasheet is totally different thing than an advertisement in Alibaba, Amazon or Ebay. A proper datasheet for example shows how the speaker impedance resistance and reactance components depend on frequency.

Comment: (continued) The electrical properties of a speaker depend much on the structure of the used cabinet. Then we should know the spectral content of your program material and have exact spec what the amp does with reactive load and with too low impedance load. If you do not give the missing data only tests reveal if something puffs its smoke out. Someone who has tried exactly the same devices can maybe tell something but you have not told any details.

Comment: What is your application? 750 watts into a reasonable efficient speaker will produce an extremely loud sound that is capable of ear damage. Are you working in a large concert hall which might require such levels.

Comment: @Barry. Whaaaaaaattttt?

Comment: 750 watts for subwoofer in an arena is worth nothing. 75000 watts probably can be felt.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I've updated my post with Subwoofer instead of sub and also put the link to their website for more details, hope someone can help

Comment: @user287001 let's pretend they provide close-enough data, I still have no idea how to check the Wattage output(or anything else) of my amp to make sure I don't blow my subs, since I can adjust my input level, boost and other on the amps I could easily blow either of them(already partially blown one of the amp but fixed it afterward)

Answer (score 1):

OK, so it's car audio.

Each of these woofers has 2 liters displacement volume at xmax, so +/- 1 liter, if we assume about 2 cubic meters volume in the car, that's a neat 1 liter per cubic meter, so an overpressure of 0.1% of sea level atmospheric pressure, or 100 Pascals, or 100 N/m². So, your windshield should not explode, although everything that is not bolted down (with loctite) will rattle. But, well, it's still 134dB acoustic, so the amount of time it takes to go deaf depends on frequency. Make sure you put on your earmuffs for testing.

Now "RMS power" doesn't mean anything. "RMS volts" does, it's the Root of Mean of Square of instantaneous voltage, which is used to calculate power in a resistive load. But it makes no sense to take the Root of Mean of Square of a power. What it usually means in audio lingo is how much average actual power it can output (or take if it's a speaker) for a reasonable amount of time without being destroyed. It's a way to distinguish the numbers from all the other fantasy sales brochure watts like musical, PMPO, etc.

Before believing such a power rating, I would like to see more details, for example for an amp "750W for 60 minutes in resistive load", or a mention of how long it takes for the thermal protection to trip, or something like that. Without these details the numbers should be taken with a grain of salt.

If these manufacturers can be trusted, then the speakers won't burn out. Note you can still destroy a woofer without exceeding its rated watts if you use an enclosure that allows it to exceed xmax and bottom out. Sealed enclosures are usually okay because the pressure inside prevents the speaker cone from going too far, but this is not the case with bass reflex or any enclosure with a vent. So you should be careful about that. Unless you're deaf, you will never burn the woofer with watts in a car, because that's way too loud and it takes a while to heat up, so you will turn it down before it fries. But if it bottoms out, it can be destroyed very quickly. So it's a good idea to do a frequency sweep at low power and find the frequency that results in maximum cone movement, then from that calculate the maximum signal level that you will allow, and set the limiter accordingly.

Note if there is a hole on the back of the speaker magnet, this is for cooling, so don't mount it against something that prevents it from sucking and blowing air in and out to cool the voice coil as the speaker moves. This also means there is no cooling at DC, so if the amp dies and outputs DC, the speakers will fry.

2x750W will require 125 Amps from 12V (assuming 100% efficiency) so the limiting factor will probably be the car's battery or alternator.

Answer (score 0):

After the questioner had inserted all data he has of the amp and the subwoofer:

Your linked data of the devices is advertisements. The plausible part is limited to mechanical dimensions and weight. We have no idea how many watts your amp can output continuously without blowing up to a perfect 4 Ohm load. The amp advertisement mentions "up to 750W RMS @ 4Ohm" What in the hell this means? I guess it's written by a person who wants people start to believe that this amp outputs continuously with no harm 750W RMS to a speaker which is sold as 4 Ohm speaker. - Welcome to Doctor Bluff's Amp and Medicine Show! It can perform as one hopes but the advertiser has never claimed it outputs continuously 750 watts to 4 Ohm and stays alive. Even less he has claimed that it stands real speakers which are totally different electric loads than resistance, no matter that there's printed 4 Ohm in the speaker.

You can try the next:

Install the speakers and the amp into your car. Get some bass rich music. Find the lowest bass sound level that you can accept as the maximum. If the parts do not stand it they were useless anyway.

Insert a limiter which absolutely prevents higher bass levels than the found minimum acceptable value for the max bass level. Of course, you should have the limiter connected in the beginning of the tests.

I have worked with limiters only in stage sound reinforcement and recording studio jobs, I cannot give recommendations which equipment is good for car audio. Car is a hostile environment, music studio gear probably disintegrate there due the vibrations. It's well possible that you may even have already something usable if you have been around car audio systems some time.